# Boolean function in for loop using numpy in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, boolean-logic

I have a question that may be simple to many of you. I am pretty new to numpy and python so if you could please help me, it would mean a ton!! I get np.logical_and

```
import numpy as np
edges= np.arange(7)
a_edges= np.arange(5)

for i in range(2):
    indexes = np.logical_and((edges>=a_edges[i]),(edges<a_edges[i+1]))

print(indexes)
[False*  True False False False False False]
```

My questions are following.
How does this output come about? For instance, is the first array of the outcome, False* (noted with asterisk), saying the first array of 'edges' not meeting both of the Boolean function for all i range (0~2)?

If that's true, the second array of 'edges' does not meet all the Boolean logic but it comes out true.

For instance, edges[1]= 1.
For i=0, edges[1] does not meet the latter logic, therefore, false. However, for i=1, edges[1] is true. So overall, it should be false......

Am I not understanding this correctly?

Thanks in advance!
Cece

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite `indexes` each iteration of the loop, so what you are seeing is the result for `i=1`. Given that, your expression becomes

```
indexes = np.logical_and(edges>=a_edges[1], edges<a_edges[2])

# equivalent to
indexes = np.logical_and(edges>=1, edges<2)
```

In other words, `True` when `edges` is 1 and `False` for everything else.

Comment: `range(2)` returns the equivalent of `[0, 1]`, yes. So first it runs with `i=0`, and then in your case runs again with `i=1` and overwrites `indexes`.

Comment: But when edges [1] doesn't hold true when i=0. How does that play a role?

Comment: Wait, is the `print()` statement in the for loop? Actually, could you edit your question so the indenting is correct?

Comment: For example, when edges=0, it is true for i=0, right? but it isn't for i=0. Should edges[0] to be also show True output?

Comment: Sorry about that. yea, no. The print(indexes) is not indented.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. When `i=0`, `indexes` is `[ True False False False False False False]`. When `i=1`, `indexes` is `[False  True False False False False False]`, as you have shown. So yes, when `i=0` then `edges[0]` is `True`, you just don't print that out.

Comment: Oh I see! I indented the print(indexes). Now, I have [ True False False False False False False]
[False  True False False False False False]. This makes a lot more sense!